# После обновления node.js npm не устанавливаются пакеты

Tags: npm

```
$ npm i @fancyapps/fancybox
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @stylelint/postcss-markdown@0.36.2: Use the original unforked package instead: postcss-markdown
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: t`введите сюда код`his library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. 
Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=        
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Svitlana\\Desktop\\Верстка\\ProdExamlple\\prod-example\\working\\wireframe\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "C:\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python310\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.10.2"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.2 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.13.2' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.13.2"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32106.194) found at:
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32106.194) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Svitlana\\Desktop\\Верстка\\ProdExamlple\\prod-example\\working\\wireframe\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Svitlana\Desktop\Верстка\ProdExamlple\prod-example\working\wireframe\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Svitlana\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-19T11_42_52_501Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Там же Вам написано: "You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio". Установите или обновите Visual Studio

Comment: Спасибо, помогла полная переустановка Visual Studio  (Desktop development with C++)